# How to create users with a predefined LanguageLocaleKey and license?

Tags: user, user-management

I'm trying to create a user via /lightning/o/User/new , but LanguageLocaleKey is required and i can't access the field to be shown in the layout. Probably i'll need the License type too.

I already stablished spanish as the only language in company settings.

[image]